# My Bootstrap datepicker always renders above the control, outside of the viewable window. How can I get it to launch below the control?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here is the aspx code that I'm using. I'm using Bootstrap 3, just downloaded the latest version this morning. Somewhat of a newb so please be patient :)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <link href="Content/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" CssClass="datepicker" class="form-control" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox> 
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the bootstrap-datepicker docs shows an example like this:

```
<div class="input-append date">
<input type="text" value="12-02-2012">
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

try putting the input-append date class in your enclosing div tag